# Snap interface - getting the OS and Browser information

Tags: haskell, browser, operating-system, haskell-snap-framework

I am using the Snap information and I was wondering if there was some type of Request function ( such as ::Request -> IO Snap() or ::Request -> Handler App App()) that returns the OS or Browser information of the user visiting the webpage.

I would like to get the OS and Browser information of the person who is visiting the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `User-Agent` HTTP header via [`getHeader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:getHeader), because [`Request`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/Snap-Core.html#t:Request) has a `HasHeaders` instance.

Example snippet:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as CS
import qualified Data.CaseInsensitive as CI
import Data.Maybe (listToMaybe)

uaName :: ByteString
uaName = CS.pack "User-Agent"
-- You can avoid CS.pack with OverloadedStrings extension.

uahName :: CI ByteString
uahName = CI.mk uaName
-- OverloadedStrings also gets rid of the CI.mk call.

getUserAgent :: Request -> Snap (Maybe ByteString)
getUserAgent rq = return . coerce $ getHeader uahName rq
 where 
    coerce :: Maybe [ByteString] -> Maybe ByteString
    coerce = (>>= listToMaybe)
    -- Some HTTP headers can appear multiple times, hence the list.
    -- `coerce` ignores all but the first occurrence.
```

For more detailed / less voluntary information, you could inject JS into an initial request and set cookies that can be extracted with [`rqCookies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-core-0.9.6.3/docs/Snap-Core.html#v:rqCookies) in a lter request.

Comment: Thanks for the help!
What are the other type of arguments other than "User-Agent"?

Comment: @kawaii5 I added an example containing a call to getHeader; does that help?